Create sprayable diaulte solution from concenrate of Eucalyptus sp oil intended for a "palm crown misting"
In Hawaii we are having a huge issue with this pest called a "rhino beetle" These beetles eat the heart of palms, eventually killing the palm completely. Soon Hawaii will have little or no more coconuts in due to this destructive invasive pest. See Beetle Damage Here
I have done some tests on live beetles and have found that they die if Eucalyptus concentrate comes into contact with them.
I have built a fogging/mister that is pressurized from water piping and hosing that goes up the palm into the crown where the beetles are attacking. Beetles are nocturnal and actively eat the palm crowns at night, thus my mister runs all night long misting the crown. The nozzles I have in the palm are letting out 2 gph (gallon per hour). The injector manufacturer confirmed the 16 oz pint will become empty once 30 gallons of water pass through it. The math is 30 gallons/2gph = 15 gallons that's 15 hours of run time that will empty the tank..
ex: 7 pm - 1hr run time w a gap between on and off stages of 30 mins of misting all night till 5am. Injecting 4oz of Eucalyptus concentrate into the injector to 12 oz of water in the pint-size injector is what I am currently doing but I don't think it's strong enough.
How concentrated can I go with the mixture of Eucalyptus oil? Is there something else I can add?
I don't want won't damage the palm or clog the spray nozzles if the mix is too thick to mist. I need some help to find a solution ratio that is strong enough to be potent for the beetle but also safe for the palm.
Any ideas? It must be organic.

Seems like you need to gather some more beetles and test them against various dilution ratios. Though there would also be the question of whether simply spraying the emulsion on the foliage/crown and leaving it works rather than "misting all night long."
